# Different Altera DE2 boards do not behave the same way

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga

I have a simple VHDL file which can be simulated correctly and that synthesizes  with Quartus II-11.0 (web edition). I can interact with switches,leds, seven segments and push buttons.

My problem is that among the 9 Altera DE2 boards I have, only 3 of them behave as expected. The FPGA seems the same...

Visually however, there are little differences on the two kind of boards, but I cannot understand why they don't behave the same :

[This one](http://www.altera.com/education/univ/materials/boards/de2/unv-de2-board.html) works as expected, while [this one](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1011/ECAD+Arch/background/DE2.html) does not (notice that e.g capacitors are not the same on the top left).

I am using exactly the same bitstream (pof or sof).

What I am missing ? Where can I find the exact info about these differences ?

Comment: What are the differences?

Comment: the differences are : push buttons do not react on 6/9 of the boards, nor probably the sliders

Comment: what are the differences ? That is my question ! Apparently same "DE2" board with same FPGA "cyclone II C35F672C6N"...so how can I guess the differences ?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say what are the differences in how your load was performing.   Are you de bouncing the switch inputs in the fpga?  Also it may be a timing problem, voltage and process differences between boards and fpgas sometimes shakes things like that out of your design.

Comment: the push buttons are said to be debounced...

Comment: Are you sure the FPGA part numbers match exactly? Over the last several years I have helped lots of kids with their DE1 issues, and this kind of issue is almost always them selecting the wrong FPGA in the project wizard.

Comment: @MattYoung : yes, sure.

Comment: Well, given the environment, perhaps they were quite forceful with the switches/sliders to where they got damaged. Wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: @Gustovo : no, I don't think that. The 3 working boards have "big blue capacitors", while the 6 other not working don't. I cannot find doc about these board revisions.

Comment: This kind of behavior is an indication of timing issues with your design, the fact that it works on some boards means that those FPGAs are slightly slower or faster than the others. You need to make sure that all signals are treated properly against jitter and noise, specially from the keys, there are lots of examples on how you can do that in a safe way on internet.

Answer (score 1):

I posted my question on altera forum : [here](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=39201)

The answer is that it is mandatory to put all unused pins to tri-state.

Comment: So, did changing that constraint fix the problem?